# Losing performance with a lot of entries exponentially

Tags: mysql

I got very very poor performance on this query to get the rank of players per leaderboard. It grows exponentially as the numbers of entries grow (as expected).
Is there a way to optimize this? I considered that i could calculate this field on every update as an alternative to this:

```
SELECT `s1`.*,COUNT(DISTINCT `s2`.`score`) AS `rank` FROM `leaderboards` `s1` 
JOIN `leaderboards` `s2` 
ON(`s1`.`score` <= `s2`.`score` AND `s1`.`leaderboard` = `s2`.`leaderboard`) 
GROUP BY `s1`.`leaderboard`,`s1`.`user_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have  proper composite index on

```
   table leaderboards (leaderboard, score)
```

and you shoud not use column in select not involved  in aggregation function and not mentioned  in group by clause 
because thsi produce unpredictable result for this columns 
this habit is deprecated  in SQL and in the most recent version of mysql produce an error

```
  SELECT `s1`.`leaderboard`,`s1`.`user_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `s2`.`score`) AS `rank` 
  FROM `leaderboards` `s1` 
  JOIN `leaderboards` `s2` ON `s1`.`score` <= `s2`.`score` 
      AND `s1`.`leaderboard` = `s2`.`leaderboard` 
  GROUP BY `s1`.`leaderboard`,`s1`.`user_id`;
```

Comment: It was all correct.. we are now using this
`SET @rank:=0;
SELECT *, @rank := IF(score = @prev, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank, @prev:=score AS prvs FROM leaderboards 
WHERE leaderboard = 'leaderboard_name'
ORDER BY score DESC;`

Comment: I don't understand your comment  ..  your question is about the code i used  in answer .. and the answer  i really cleat  .. in your comment you have different code  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
try as below:

ALTER TABLE `leaderboards` ADD INDEX (`leaderboard`); 

SELECT `s1`.*,COUNT(DISTINCT `s2`.`score`) AS `rank` 
FROM `leaderboards` `s1` 
LEFT JOIN `leaderboards` `s2` 
ON(`s1`.`score` <= `s2`.`score` AND `s1`.`leaderboard` = `s2`.`leaderboard`) 
GROUP BY `s1`.`leaderboard`,`s1`.`user_id`;
```